# Building Websites only on NodeJs and Express blocking requests over http

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, socket.io

I have a question regarding the examples out there when using Nodejs, Express and Jade for templates.

All the examples show how to build some sort of a user administrative interface where you can add user profiles, delete them and manage them.

Those are considered beginner's guides to NodeJs. My question is around the fact that if I have have 10 users concurrently accessing the same interface and doing the same operations, surely NodeJs will block the requests for the other users as they are running on the same port.

So let's say I am pulling out a list of users which may be something like 10000. Yes I can do paging, but that is not the point. While I am getting the list from the server another 4 users want to access the application. They have to wait for my process to end. That is my question - how can one avoid that using NodeJS & Express?

I am on this issue for a couple of months! I currently have something in place that does the following:

1. Run the main processing of stuff on a port
2. Run a Socket.io process on a different port
3. Use a sticky session
4. The idea is that I do a request (like getting a list of items), and immediately respond with some request reference but without the requested items, thus releasing the port.
5. In the background "asynchronously" I then do the process of getting the items. Upon which when completed, I do an http request from one node to the socket node port node SENDING the items through.
6. When that is done I then perform a socket.io emit WITH the data and the initial request reference so that the correct user gets the message.
7. On the client side I have an event listening for the socket which then completes the ajax request by populating the list.

I have SOME success in doing this! It actually works to a degree! I have an issue online which complicates matters due to ip addresses, and socket.io playing funny.

I also have multiple workers using clustering. I use it in the following manner:

1. I create a master worker
2. I spawn workers
3. I take any connection request and pass it to the relevant worker.

I do that for the main node request as well as for the socket requests. Like I said I use 2 ports!

As you can see I have had a lot of work done on this and I am not getting  a proper solution!

My question is this - have I gone all around the world 10 times only to have missed something simple? This sounds way to complicated to achieve a non-blocking nodejs only website.

I asked myself - surely all these tutorials would have not missed on something as important as this! But they did!

I have researched, read, and tested a lot of code - this is my very first time I ask anything on stackoverflow!

Thank you for any assistance.

P.S. One example of the same approach is this: I request a report using jasper, I pass parameters, and with the "delayed ajax response" approach as described above I simply release the port, and in the background a very intensive report is being generated (and this can be very intensive process as a lot of calculations are being performed)..! I really don't see a better approach - any help will be super appreciated!

Thank you for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say it, but yes, you have been going around the world 10 times only to have been missing something simple.

It's obvious that your previous knowledge/experience with webservers are from a blocking point of view, and if this was the case, your concerns had been valid.

Node.js is a framework focused around using a single thread to execute code, which means if it does any blocking operations, no one else would be able to get anything done.

There are some operations that can do this in node, like reading/writing to disk. However, most node operations will be asynchronous.

I believe you are familiar with the term, so I won't go into details. What asynchronous operations allows node to do, is to keep this single thread idle as much as possible. By idle I mean open for other work. If your code is fully asynchronous, then handling 4 concurrent users (or even 400) shouldn't be a problem, even for a single thread.

Now, in regards to your initial problem of ports: Once a request is received on a given port, node.js execute whatever code you have written for it, until it encounters an asynchronous operation as soon as that happens, it is available to to pick up more requests on the same port.

The second problem you inquire about, is the database operation. In this case, node-js would send the query to the database (which takes no time at all) and the database does that actual execution of the query. In the meantime, node is free to do whatever it wants, until the database is finished, and lets node know there is a result to fetch.

You can recognize async operations by their structure: my_function(..., ..., callback). Function that uses a callback function, is in most cases asynch.

So bottom line: Don't worry about the problems around blocking IO, as you will hardly encounter any in node. Use a single port if you want (By creating multiple child processes, you can even have multiple node instances on the same port).

Hope this explains it good enough. If you have any further questions, let me know :)

Comment: Hi - thank you for your answer, and I understand it fully, but: I came across the problem as soon as I had 2 users reading from the database the list as described! While in things like PHP is normal practice! Think of a drop-down with a list of options! One user's drop down will fetch the list, while the other is waiting for the first user to finish populating the list, and only then the 2nd one is populated! So unfortunately I do have to worry about this! Child processes are as many as there are cpu's available! To get the list I am sending the request to an express router 'get_list'.

Comment: Is the query complicated? It might be that the sql server is the problem here. Could you copy and paste your database-connection/config code and SQL? (Leave out any username and password,etc); It might be that you are not using pooled connections to your database, requiring node to send one query only after the first finished.

Comment: Hi Stian - the thing is not only about a database! I have for example the need to compile a report using Jasper. The minute I press print, it will take my request, compile the report, run and do calculations, and will spit back a link which then I use to download the pdf file that was created by the report. That could be an extreme case of long running script! So whether is an sql, mongo or a report, the point is that I am still blocking the port while waiting for something to come back. In a php example I would not block any other user, but in node it blocks any other requests to that port.

Comment: I see. Well it looks to me that the problem you are experiencing is that the code you are running is taking too long, not allowing node to tend to other connections while it's running.

There is unfortunaly to each way to solve this, if the code you are running isn't asynch. The only solution here is to either have another process do this heavy stuff, and give some temporary feedback to the user (ex. a link to where the report will appear or so)

It does seem weird that things like that will cause such problems, but I have no experience with Jasper, so I can't really be sure how it works :)

Comment: I created a simple script! It displays "Hello World"! Passing a parameter "?foo=bar", the message will be displayed only after 5 seconds. It mimics a long running query. Now access the same page in two different browser session. One with the query string, and the other without! The one with query will cause the second request without to be delayed until it has finished processing! THAT is the problem which will affect ANY website. Because if you cause a delay on anything like getting a user list then the website is a total flop. So how can you use node for simple websites truly then???

Comment: Could you post your Hello world code here? Might be the way you simulate the query or something. I had a nodeserver serving 100+ concurrent users with queries taking 60 seconds (because of a bad query) but no performance loss on the webserver or for the end-users not accessing the bad query.

Comment: Stian - thanks for coming back to me! Let me give you a simple other example! My initial short code was to create a sleep function simulating a long query. I KNOW that is a blocking function, but let's put it in a different context. Let's say I need to send an ajax query which in turn creates a web service call to a different server and does something that takes long. Why is it then all users now utilizing the same port will be blocked? Because that is what will happen if my initial ajax call requires for the web  service to complete before responding with a suitable result?

Comment: Without a concrete code example, I can't tell you anything other than that node is async, and such a situation as you are creating is very unlikely a problem if you just keep it simple. Only a blocking action would create this problem, and sending requests to external applications shouldnt be blocking unless you spesifically make it so.

Comment: // simple example
router.post('/create_transaction', function (req, res, next) {
 var ws = new webService();
 var data = req.body;

 ws.calMethod('create_transaction', data, function(response){
  data.response = response;
  res.send(data);
  res.end();
 });
});

Comment: Hi - sorry I am new to this! I see there is no code formatting. Here is a fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/bamLssLh

Comment: Great, that example explains a lot :)

It appears that the webservice you are talking about, is actually a blocking piece of code. Depending on how much you can edit that code, I believe you could try some of the following solutions:

1. Make the blocking code async;  This requires you to be able to alter the code that interacts with the terminal.
2. Create multiple processes and load-balance them;  If all requests are able to block node, then you can have max users = #cores on the machine running the node application.

Option 1 is therefor much better, but requires more planning/work